# Images uploaded with PHP on IIS can't be accessed due to '401 Unauthorized: access is denied due to invalid credentials' error message

Tags: php, image, iis, http-status-code-401

I have the following PHP script to upload images to my site:

```
function saveImage2Server($input_name)
{
    $originalFileName = basename($_FILES[$input_name]["name"]);
    $fileType = exif_imagetype($_FILES[$input_name]["tmp_name"]);
    $fileSize = $_FILES[$input_name]["size"];
    $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
    $maxSize = 819200;

    // first check if the file is of allowed type
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowedTypes))
    {
        //check if the size is under 800kb
        if($fileSize<=$maxSize)
        {
            $dotIndex = strrpos($originalFileName, ".");
            $extension = strtolower(substr($originalFileName, $dotIndex));

            $newFileName = uniqid().uniqid().$extension;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$input_name]["tmp_name"], "../../images/".$newFileName);
            return $newFileName;
        }
        else // if it's above 800kb
        {
            echo("The file size exceeds 800kb");
            header("Location: ../");
            die(error);
        }
    }
    else // if the type isn't allowed
    {
        echo("This file type isn't allowed");
        header("Location: ../");
        die(error);
    }
}
```

The script works fine on my local server (WAMP), after the files are uploaded I'm able to access them normally. But when on IIS - the files are being uploaded, but when trying to access them, I'm getting this 401 error message: `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`

What can I or my hosting company do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the IIS user has write access to the directory on which your images are being uploaded.

Comment: Apparently, they had something wrong with the authorization inheritance. They also blocked the ini_set, for security reasons, so I couldn't deal with it myself. Now everything works fine. Thank you for your reply!